# SQL syntax creating table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

What is the issue with the following SQL to create the table? It's executed in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE friend_recommend(
  UID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  FID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  MID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
  DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (UID, FID, MID)
)
```

The error is:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, FID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL, MID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NUL' at line 2

---

Comment: what error did mysql give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whats a VARCHAR2 ?
try changing it to VARCHAR

```
CREATE TABLE friend_recommend(
  UID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  FID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  MID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  DATE TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (UID, FID, MID)
)
```

Comment: VARCHAR2 is an Oracle datatype, there is no such creature in MySQL.